# NullPointerException-webdriver null

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

I put a screenshot with `getDriverInstance`.

[image]

After run.

[image: When I run the test, I get this error.]

When I run the test, I get this error.

At debug it tells me, that the `WebDriver` is `null`.

Can anyone help me with a solution how to fix the problem?

[[image: I don't know what the problem is here. At debug it tells me that the webdriver is null. Can anyone help me with a solution how to fix the problem? ][2]]
[image: He tells me that the web driver is null, can anyone help me how to fix the problem?]

I don't understand why a `WebDriver` would be `null`.

Comment: what is threadwebdriver.getdriverinstance()

Comment: And .getDriver() looks like this. 
public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

Comment: @PDHide, would it be easier for you if I put a git link with the code?